# PHP echoing a specific amount of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database with 100 names, dates, id's, and other stuff. I want to be able to get a specific amount of rows echoed in a div, and then another specific amount in the next and so on.

I have been looking at foreach and break here, cause my googling kind of sent me there.. but maybe im looking at the wrong thing:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

I just don't seem to get things right.

This is a school project and I know this is maybe a little bit vague, sorry about that.

Something like this:

```
<div id="div1"> echo row 1-7 </div>
<div id="div2"> echo row 7-19 </div>
<div id="div3"> echo row 20-44 </div>
```

and so on...

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: @zackt147 that's bad, why call the database numerous times, when you can call it just once and parse it?

Comment: @Thor You need to use some kind of counter. You can do some kind of modular arithmetic if you want to see when you need to start a new row. Look at this http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php on how to do your SQL calls. Then look at http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php to see how Mod works. Mod will only work if it's a set number of things, but it looks like you are doubling the amount of data everytime, so it should be pretty simple. You'll just need to figure out the math behind it.

Comment: @Matt this is a pagination exercise... what if the table contained 50,000 rows... it would be stupid to pull all of those down so you can show 50.

Comment: zackt147 you make a good point, but that is a bigger discussion on the best way to optimize large data sets. In the spirit of educating @Thor you could research working with and parsing large data sets. This would lead you down a road of dealing with memcache perhaps for caching your results. PHP can handle fairly large data sets, however, performance can become an issue once traffic on your site increases. But again, that is a bigger discussion.

Comment: @Orangepill yes, then use limits, but he said it's only 100 items in the database. If it is a pagination exercise, then yes go ahead and use limit to understand how it works.

Comment: @Thor what's the criteria for separating them - why are they separated? that would help us answer better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it directly in your query

Use at the end of your query this:

```
<div id="div1"> echo row 1-7 </div>  use "LIMIT 0,6"
<div id="div2"> echo row 7-19 </div>  use "LIMIT 7, 19"
<div id="div3"> echo row 20-44 </div> use "LIMIT 20,44"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a numerically indexed array holding your rows you could do something like:

```
<div id="div1">
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    print $yourArray[Si]['some_field'];
} ?>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<?php for ($i = 8; $i <= 19; $i++) {
    print $yourArray[Si]['some_field'];
} ?>
</div>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not tested) might work:

```
$id=1;
$count=0;
$limit=20;
foreach($row as $r){
  if ($count==0) echo "<div id='div$id'>";
  echo $r;
  if ($count++==$limit){
    $count=0;
    $id++;
    echo "</div>\n";
  };
}
if ($count!=0) echo "</div>";
```